how to know which field(category) most used
can I do this in one single query Note: order should not be changed.
products = Product.objects.filter(
    title__icontains=self.query
    ).values('id', 'is_featured', 'category_id').order_by('-is_featured', 'rank', '-created')

most_used_category = products.values('category_id') \
.annotate(category_count=Count('category_id')) \
.order_by('-category_count').first()


Share the correspoding models, what is the category? You here share Product?

I also don't really understand what you mean with "and above result". The most used category is something different than your Product query (?)?

I am getting result already what I want I just need to know at same time most used category id that in queryset that is it

I want my query also send most used category id at same time
